# How to display inputted text in a TextView after clicking a button in Android studio?

Tags: android, button, text, input, textview

So I am experimenting with Android Studio. I am stuck in the part where I want my "Submit" button to display the user inputted text underneath the page.

Button submit is the button.
"name" and "email" are the EditText variables a.k.a text fields
My TextView variable is outputText

So after the user enters random stuff in both text fields and click submit, I want my outputText to display both texts that were inputted in 2 separate lines

ex:

John Smith

john.smith@gmail.com

The code below is my .java code for the activity. I need to know how to initialize the new intent in a way that lets me do the 4 lines below it. Thanks.

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v){
    Button submit = (Button) v;

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i =
                    new Intent(...?...);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    textout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textout.setText(editName.getText()+" "+editEmail.getText());


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want my outputText to display both texts that were inputted in 2
>   separate lines

Use `<br>`  and `Html.fromHtml` between text to add new line:

```
String strText=(String)editName.getText()+"<br>"+(String)editEmail.getText();
textout.setText(Html.fromHtml(strText));
```

> how to initialize the new intent in a way that lets me do the 4 lines
>   below it...

```
Intent i =new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this,TargetActivityName.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Why would I want a TargetActivityName? I want the output text to be displayed in the same activity...

Comment: @btrballin: then no need to start same activity again just use `extout.setText(Html.fromHtml(strText));` inside on submit Button click

Comment: I'm confused. How where does the getText and setText stuff go and how are they linked to the initialization of Intent i?

Comment: @btrballin: if you want to update text of `textout` then now need to use Intent and startActivity in onClick method just use same code

Comment: Ok nvm I never had to start an intent. I posted my solution on the button. Thanks a lot for your quick replies.

Comment: @btrballin: comment `ntent submitI = new Intent(Login.this, Login.class); startActivity(submitI);` line then try

Comment: So far I've used intents for URL buttons and a button that takes you to a different activity. Since all the buttons I've messed around with used Intents, I thought every button needed to, but it was different here because the button's function is static.

Answer (score 0):

For print in next line

```
textout.setText(editName.getText()+"\n"+editEmail.getText());
```

For intent

```
Intent i =new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What are those two parameters supposed to be for intent? I've always seen it initialized differently with 2 parameters for different types of actions.

Comment: You can use intent for different use and different ways, This is for  launching a new activity. "Firstactivity" is the current activity name and "secondactivity" is the activity you want to start. For more info check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to accomplish what I wanted without an Intent initialized. Here's the code:

```
    public void buttonOnClick(){
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    textout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             textout.setText(editName.getText()+"\n"+editEmail.getText());
        }
    });


}
```